# Getting count from aggregate function in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, syntax-error, aggregate

I am quite new to MongoDB use in C#. I am trying to get the amount of Tickets (documents) that match a specific `EmployeeId`. I have this function in MongoDb:

```
db.Tickets.aggregate([
{$match: {employeeId: 3}},
{$count: "count"}
]);
```

(the number 3 was just an example)

this returns the following: `{count: 4}`, which is correct. I want to get that count number on C# in Visual Studio.

So far I have created this method in Visual Studio:

```
public int GetUserTicketCount(User user)
{
  int count = collectionOfTickets.Aggregate()
  .Match(x => x.employeeId == user.GetEmployeeId())
  .Count()
  .FirstOrDefault()
  .Count();           
}
```

From what I have searched in SO and other forums, this method should work; however I am getting an error of "`AggregateCountResult` does not contain a definition for `Count` and no accessible extension `Count` accepting a first argument of type `AggregateCountResult` could be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)".

How may I solve this, or how may I get the count result in C#? Any and all help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count is a property, not a method.

`.Count` should work. Just remove the parentheses.

See the official docs here: http://rstam.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_AggregateCountResult.htm.

Comment: I've done that, and at least the error is gone. However, when I display this number on a listView, it shows as `Systems.Collections.Generic.List'1[databaseName.Ticket]`. However, this is a big improvement! Ill be looking more into this to solve it.